# How to fix "django.contrib.gis.geoip2 has no attribute GeoIP2"

Tags: django, python-3.x, geoip2

I am trying to retrieve my visitors' location.
After successfully retrieving the IP Adress I want to use
the GeoIP2 object to get information about the location.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/gis/geoip2/#django.contrib.gis.geoip2.GeoIP2

In my settings.py file I added 'django.contrib.gis.geoip2' to my installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.gis.geoip2',
    'web'
]
```

Using the shell everything works perfect [python3 manage.py shell]:

> > > dir(django.contrib.gis.geoip2)

```
['GeoIP2', 'GeoIP2Exception', 'HAS_GEOIP2', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'base', 'geoip2', 'resources']
```

However trying to use the GeoIP2 object in my application 'web' I get the error: "django.contrib.gis.geoip2 has no attribute GeoIP2".

```
['HAS_GEOIP2', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a dependency mentioned in the documentation you link to, which you are missing on your web server:

> In order to perform IP-based geolocation, the GeoIP2 object requires the [geoip2 Python library](https://pypi.org/project/geoip2/)

You need to install this with `pip install geoip2`.

Note that the documentation also mentions other requirements which you also need to set in order to use this module.

Comment: The issue was I used the wrong virtual environment.